# when to use UriTemplate in REST WCF service

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

i have simple interface that i want to test it out but i have'nt understood when to use URITemplate:

how would i access XMLData in this case...?

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        string XMLData(string id);

 public class RestServiceImpl : IRestServiceImpl
    {    
        public string XMLData(string id)
        {
            return "my xml data:" + id;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UriTemplate is some kind alike of masking your method.  Example:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "myMethod/{id}")]  
string XMLData(string id);
```

you may now call the method this way:

```
http://localhost/RestServiceImpl/myMethod/inputIdstring
```

instead of...

```
http://localhost/RestServiceImpl/XMLData?id=inputIdstring
```

I hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

By default, if you don't specify a `UriTemplate`, WCF will supply one for you that uses a query string format, such as this:

```
XMLData?id={id}
```

However, you might want a RESTful URI, instead, like this:

```
xmldata/{id}
```

For those cases, you add a `UriTemplate`. If you don't need anything but the default semantics, feel free to leave it off.

Comment: if i use for RESTful URI for POST data than how would i do?

Comment: @Randolpho Please edit your your answer so I can take back my accidental down vote.